# Select a range of VARCHAR values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `VARCHAR(100)` column called `SerialNumber` on my `Devices` table with values like this:

```
SN10001
SN10002
SN10003
SN10004
...etc
```

How do I select all records between `SN15000` AND `SN20000` in MySQL?

MySQL version is `8.0.12` and we cannot assume that the serial number will always have 5 numbers after the `SN`.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Always SN followed by a 5 digit number? Do you want a numeric comparison of the integer part, or a string comparison, is e.g. SN17 supposed to be returned or not?

Comment: Added the details requested.

Comment: So would 'SN150AX' be in the range? Would 'SN1600B' and 'SN1600'? If you store strings and you want to look at ranges, these strings should define the ranges. In my opinion above strings would be in the range as they start with SN15 and SN16. If you want the numbers to be treated separately, i.e. 'SN1600' is supposed to mean 'SN' and 1600, then store the two values in separate rows. Or store fixed lengths, as your example suggests (e.g. 'SN01600').

Comment: You say _"we cannot assume that the serial number will always have 5 numbers after the SN"_, but all you sample data has a 5 digit number...

Comment: @Ciwan: The sample data is not helpful at all. And we still don't know, what exactly the format for a serial number is. Is it always starting with SN? (If so, why store it?) And what can follow? Digits only in variable length? Digits and letters, but always five of them? ... After all you haven't even told us what your probelm is and where your own algorithm (?) or query (?) failed. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

- You can use [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to replace `SN` substring with empty string in the `SerialNumber` column.
- Then, we can [`Cast()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the modified string to Unsigned integer value.
- Eventually, use `Where` condition to match the range as required.

You can try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Devices 
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(SerialNumber, 'SN', '') AS UNSIGNED) >= 15000 AND 
      CAST(REPLACE(SerialNumber, 'SN', '') AS UNSIGNED) <= 20000 AND 
      SerialNumber LIKE 'SN%'
```

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya, but I think the last line needs to be `<= 2000`

Comment: @Ciwan you are looking upto `SN20000` as per your question

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I fixed what OP was referring to

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` collation and `utf8` character set does not select the correct data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sF8akzj9wjSCdePRfMwCDA/0

Comment: And your first condition is simply removing 'SN' from the string, so any other devices that may just have numbers (ie. `SerialNumber=16000`) would match. You should at least check additionally: `SerialNumber LIKE 'SN%'`

Comment: @FrankerZ edited. the basic assumption in my second result was that user will have SN01600 insted of SN1600

Comment: Do all serial numbers begin with "SN"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MySQL 8, you can take advantage of regex functions. You can get the result using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Devices
WHERE SerialNumber REGEXP '^SN\\d+$'
AND REGEXP_REPLACE(SerialNumber, '[^\\d]+', '') BETWEEN 15000 and 20000;
```

First, we match to ensure it's `SN` followed by some numbers. Secondly, we replace anything that isn't a number with nothing, and then check if it's between 15000 and 20000. An example can be seen [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sF8akzj9wjSCdePRfMwCDA/3).

While the above query solves your answer, this will cause some [particularly nasty row-scans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html) on the table, which could lead to some really bad performance the bigger the table gets.

I recommend reformatting your structure a bit better (Especially if this table is going to get large, and searches like this are going to happen often), so that you can search using indexes:

1. Add 2 columns: `string_part` and `int_part` on Devices. Add an index on both fields `` (`string_part`, `int_part`) ``. When you insert/update the data, either create a trigger, or programatically split apart the data, and insert the separated data into their respective fields. (#3 shows you how to do this with virtual columns.) Then you can search the database, efficiently:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM Devices 
   WHERE string_part = 'SN' AND int_part >= 15000 AND int_part <= 20000
   ```
2. Ensure all your data is a consistent length ie exactly 5 integer parts: (SN00001, SN10000). Then simply compare by string. In this case `SN1500` would never be in your data (it would be `SN01500`) and wouldn't be matched by the following:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM Devices 
   WHERE SerialNumber >= 'SN15000' AND SerialNumber <= 'SN20000'
   ```
3. Use Virtual Columns, and add an index on that column. An example can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sF8akzj9wjSCdePRfMwCDA/4). Notice the query times (100ms to 1ms):

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Devices (
     `SerialNumber` VARCHAR(20),
     `SerialNumberString` VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_SUBSTR(SerialNumber, '^[A-Za-z]+')) VIRTUAL,
     `SerialNumberInteger` INT(11) UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_SUBSTR(SerialNumber, '\\d+$')) VIRTUAL,
     INDEX `SerialNumberIndex` (`SerialNumberString`, `SerialNumberInteger`)
   ) DEFAULT charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
   ```

   And your query:

   ```
   SELECT SerialNumber
   FROM Devices
   WHERE SerialNumberString = 'SN' AND SerialNumberInteger BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all serial numbers between 'SN15000' and 'SN20000' including the two, you can just use `BETWEEN` (otherwise you'd use `<` and `>`):

```
select *
from mytable
where serial_number  between 'SN15000' and 'SN20000';
```

In case you allow for shorter and longer serial numbers add a length condition:

```
select *
from mytable
where serial_number  between 'SN15000' and 'SN20000'
and char_length(serial_number) = 7;
```

Comment: This does not work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sF8akzj9wjSCdePRfMwCDA/1

Comment: I don't see how this simple query could possibly fail. The DB fiddle link opens empty. Is there anything I must do to see content?

Comment: @FrankerZ: Your sample may contain invalid data. From the sample it looks like serial numbers start with two letters and then continue with five digits. Your data does not follow that rule.

Comment: Where does OP state that all numbers are five digits long?

Comment: Ugh, I'm going to remove the downvote, but this is an incredibly hackish solution. What if OP wants to select all where numbers are between 7000 and 15000? There would be no way, using this solution.

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea to have serial numbers of different lengths? `SN1`, `SN10`, `SN100`, are all perfectly fine serial numbers.

Comment: It is only a bad idea to store serial numbers in different lengths, if the OP is interested in ranges - which apperantly they are. So the numbers should either be fixed length or letters and number should be stored in separate columns. The query is only fighting a bad database design or content hence. It would be way better to get the data straight.